# Further simplifying and shortening a simple grouping algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

This is the input list

```
input_list = ['string','string','1','string','2','string','string','3','string','5']
```

This is the output required

```
    [['string', 'string', '1'], ['string', '2'], ['string', 'string', '3'], 
     ['string', '5']]
```

Basically you're grouping the list data `string` and `(numeric data)` into a list of lists, each list containing the first numeric data and previous string data encountered

A simple algorithm which can accomplish this

```
output_list = []
inner_list = []
for data in input_list:
    inner_list.append(data)
    if data.isdigit():
        output_list.append(inner_list)
        inner_list = []

print output_list
```

I was wondering if this could be made even simpler (accomplished in lesser number of lines)?

Comment: you can save 1 line `inner_list.append(data)` (can be done unconditionally) and after the positive check `if data.isdigit():` you don't need the `else`. Elimination of two lines

Comment: @Ronald Yes,  edited :) I meant could this be accomplished in a much more simpler way without creating all these `inner_list` temp variables

Answer (score 3):

One liner with `reduce`. **Do not use**.

```
reduce(lambda n, e: n[:-1]+[n[-1]+[e]] + ([[]] if e.isdigit() else []), input_list, [[]])[:-1]
```

Comment: too computationally expensive?

Answer (score 3):

You can first find the index of digit elements then use `zip` to create the desire slice indices and slice you list :

```
>>> ind=[0]+[i for i,j in enumerate(input_list,1) if j.isdigit()]
>>> [input_list[i:j] for i,j in zip(ind,ind[1:])]
[['string', 'string', '1'], ['string', '2'], ['string', 'string', '3'], ['string', '5']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is a single line solution, it is not simpler, it's more complex:

```
input_list = ['string','string','1','string','2','string','string','3','string','5']
result = [s.split() for s in ' '.join([s+'\n' if s.isdigit() else s for s in input_list]).splitlines()]
print result
```

Output:

```
[['string', 'string', '1'], ['string', '2'], ['string', 'string', '3'], ['string', '5']]
```

Is this blob of complex code what you want?

(Note the bug: if one of the strings should already contain a `\n`. You could choose another character if you know for sure that it won't be in one of the strings).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a (slightly evil) `reduce()`-based version:

```
def reduce_string_prefix(cur, item):
    cur[-1].append(item)
    if item.isdigit():
        cur.append([])
    return cur

input_list = ['string', 'string', '1', 'string', '2', 'string', 'string', '3', 'string', '5']
output_list = reduce(reduce_string_prefix, input_list, [[]])[:-2]
```

I'm not so sure if this is actually easier to read, though ;-).